# "may have" vs "might have"

Tags: word-choice

Suppose my teacher gives Me and my friend homework. After completing the homework, my friend comes to my house to be sure if he has done his homework correctly or not. He asks me "have I completed my homework correctly?" It seems to me that there is something wrong with his homework. Can I reply "No, I think you ***may have/might have*** made a mistake."

'May' or 'might': Which one is correct in the given context? I think both are correct but "might" expresses less probability. I am not sure.

Answer (score -1):

If you truly believe you are right in finding the mistake, the word "might have" is used... 
If you yourself have a doubt in the mistake, the word "may have" is used to ensure that both you and the friend checks said mistake...

Might have: You are **sure** there is a mistake and it's basically one-sided (Your friend finds the mistake) 
May Have: You are **unsure** about the mistake and its two-fold (Both you and your friend solves the mistake)